# Taylor polynomial with little-$o$ inside, and derivative of little-$o$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider $f(x)$ to be a function with it's Taylor series given by $f(x) = 1-x+3x^2 + o(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$.
To write down the second order Taylor polynomial of $\ln(f)$ I met some difficulties. Indeed

$$\ln(f) = \ln(1-x + 3x^2 + o(x^2))$$

and to work with Taylor Polynomial I need to understand how $o(x)$ works when inside a function or when derived.

$$\ln(f)\big|_{x = 0} = \ln(1 + o(0)) = \ln(1) = 0$$

What is exactly $o(0)$? I treated it as zero...

Now

$$\text{first derivative} = \frac{-1+6x + o'(x^2)}{1-x+3x^2 + o(x^2)}$$

What is $o'(x^2)$? How to treat it and the other little $-o$ in the denominator?
Thank you !!

Comment: A generic little $o$ may behave very badly! Strictly speaking, it is not even necessarily true that your $f$ is continuous anywhere except at $0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Uhm, I don't know what to say actually :D I added a detail in the question, but I don't know if it's relevant... The text of the exercises is that... I'm asked for $T_2$ fo $\ln(f)$.

Comment: You don't need to differentiate $\ln(f)$ in order to calculate its 2nd order Taylor polynomial. Simply apply
$$\ln(1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}2+o(u^2)$$
with $u$ replaced by $-x+3x^2+o(x^2).$

Comment: In general, never (ever) try to take the derivative of a $o()$ or $O()$ term. There is no generic relationship between the size of a function and the size of its derivative.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, thank you so much!! How would I treat the term
$$o((-x + 3x^2 + o(x^2))^2)$$

Comment: Since $x^2=o(x),$ we have $-x + 3x^2 + o(x^2)\sim-x$ hence $u^2\sim x^2$ and $o(u^2)=o(x^2).$ Note that there are also $o(x^2)$ terms when you expand $\frac{u^2}2$. Actually,  (again) $u^2=x^2+o(x^2).$